# Prevent UWP app opening when notification is clicked

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, push-notification, notifications

I am building a UWP app which receives notifications via a notification hub on Azure. My code is essentially like this [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification), which is working perfectly. I just need to stop the UWP app opening whenever a user clicks the notification, essentially doing nothing instead. How can I do this, I can not find a direct answer online that works for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prevent UWP app opening when notification is clicked

When you click toast, it will launch the app by default. But, we could specific action button and set the `ToastActivationType` as `Background` or set toast `activationType="background"` directly. When you click the button, it will launch the background but not the app. For more please refer [handling-background-activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast#handling-background-activation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solution Is correct, but I needed to just look into it a bit. I was sending a xaml notification from the notification hub test window. and needed to set the entire notification to background by setting the opening tag as <toast activationType="background">. This will stop the notification from opening the app. It is confusing as actions can be set background in xaml, but not achieve the correct result for me(like the linked article)